# Why would this code work in IE and fail in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, browser

So loading up our new web application in Firefox and Chrome I had an alert subtly tell me that a tabStrip couldn't be found. Following through the code I found this function:

```
function initializeTabStrip() {
    var tblList = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    var tabStrip = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < tblList.length; ++i) {
        if (typeof (tblList[i].tabStripRoot) != "undefined") {
            tabStrip = tblList[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (tabStrip) {
        window.tabStrip = new TabStrip(tabStrip);
    }
    else {
        alert("couldn't find tabstrip");
    }
}
```

In both Firefox and Chrome, `typeof (tblList[i].tabStripRoot)` comes up to be undefined, whereas in Internet Explorer the same section of code will find an item, and follow through correctly.

I've tried using Firebug and IE's developer toolbar script debugging tool to follow through and attempt to discover what 'tabStripRoot' is, but I haven't had any luck.

Would any of you JavaScript guru's be able to give me some direction into why one out of three browsers works?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're relying on IE's non-standard ability to access arbitrary attributes as properties of DOM elements.

In standards-compliant browsers, you cannot write `someElement.tabStripRoot` to access the `tabStripRoot` attribute.

Change it to `tblList[i].getAttribute('tabStripRoot')`.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Thanks!

Comment: He's saying that the custom atttribute (tabStripRoot) only works as a property for MSIE but not standards-compliant browsers. Oh, and as he said, just replace it with his code and it would work with all browsers.

Comment: While changing the code to getAttribute does stop the alert from firing I now cycle through all elements in the list. Is "getAttribute()" case sensitive, as in "tabStripRoot" is not the same as "tabstriproot" ?